# Key bindings in windows disrupt key shortcuts in visual studio IDE

Tags: visual-studio, ide, windows-11

In my keyboard F11 and F12 are for volume control but when I'm debugging in visual studio IDE F11 is mapped to "jump into" command.

but when I press F11 during debug it just controls the volume like it is mapped to in windows.

I tried using power toys app to map the volume to other keys but when I do it the F11 in visual studio IDE debug does nothing.

Can anyone help me with this ?

I have windows 11 pro